# How to get rid of instanseof in javascript

Tags: javascript, class, oop, instanceof

I have a class, it has two methods: `get()`, `set()`.

```
function A() {
    var value = '';
    this.get = function () {
        return value;
    };
    this.set = function (v) {
        value = v;
    };
}
```

And I have a function `f()`:

```
/**
 *
 * @param { String | Number } b
 */
function f(b){
    var value;
    if(b instanceof A){
        value = b.get();
    }else{
        value = b;
    }
}
```

I could create an object:

```
var test = new A();
test.set('Hello');
f(test); //Hello
f(10); //10
```

The `instanceof` operator tests whether an object has in its prototype chain the prototype property of a constructor. 
I heard it is a bad practice use this operator.
The question is: Is it imposible to get rid of `instanceof` operator from my code?
Maybe I should use force type conversion or use another getter, setter?

> <--UPDATE-->>

I found simple solution, I could coerce `b.get` to boolean type and check it. It works, but maybe it has incidental effect.

```
 value = (!!b.get) ? b.get(): b;
```

> <--UPDATE 2-->>

Another way: `value = (b.constructor = A) ? b.get(): b;`

Comment: *I heard it is a bad practice use this operator* - I can't think of why it would be. In this specific case though, you could be testing for the existence of the method `get()` rather than checking for a specific implementation of `A`

Comment: In this case you could use typeof operator.

Answer (score 2):

It's not the `instanceof` operator itself which is the problem, it's what you're using it for. Your function is expecting values of two different types: either an instance of `A` which needs to be handled a certain way or anything else which can be used as is.

The problem with this is a) why is your function allowing two different types to begin with and couldn't you harmonise that into just one type, and b) if it's accepting "anything" or "`A`", why `A` specifically and not something more general?

Assuming that you cannot reasonably change point a), you can at least make b) better:

```
if (typeof b.get == 'function') {
    value = b.get();
}
```

You've just made your function a little more flexible and adaptable to future change by testing for the actual thing you're interested in: a `get` method. That `b` is an `instanceof A` is sort of irrelevant for the task at hand and may limit you in the future.